# installing R Studio on Red Hat Enterprise Linux

Tags: linux, rstudio, redhat

I'm trying to install rstudio on redhat linux machine using the command below but I get the following errors

```
$ sudo yum install https://download1.rstudio.org/rstudio-0.99.489-x86_64.rpm

Error: Package: rstudio-0.99.489-1.x86_64 (/rstudio-0.99.489-x86_64)
       Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit)

Error: Package: rstudio-0.99.489-1.x86_64 (/rstudio-0.99.489-x86_64)
       Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit)

Error: Package: rstudio-0.99.489-1.x86_64 (/rstudio-0.99.489-x86_64)
       Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
```

So,I tried running

```
$ sudo yum install libc.so.6

Package glibc-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.i686 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

$ sudo yum install libstdc++.so.6

Package libstdc++-4.4.7-16.el6.i686 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Looks like glib and libstd are already installed. Probably R studio is not looking in the right dir for the libs. Can some one help me to troubleshoot this? I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: I think questions related to installation don't belongs to stackoverflow.... You can migrate your question to superuser..

Comment: And when doing this you should mention version information and bitness of your rhel

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have a 32 bit system (see the `i686` in the installed package name)

```
Package libstdc++-4.4.7-16.el6.i686 already installed and latest version Nothing to do
```

While you are installing a 64 bit package (see the `x86_64` in the package name)

Answer (score 0):

---

As you can read from the text https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/ ,,, the RHEL packages are for RHEL 7 :

> Fedora 19+/RedHat 7+/openSUSE 13.1+

You have RHEL 6 : Nothing to do. Unless you can build the source code https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/

---

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install the server version and access it using browser, see installation instructions (select Redhat/CentOS tab) here:https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download-server/

Answer (score 0):

Try instaling older version of rstudio from archives here https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/206569407-Older-Versions-of-RStudio 
I was using Red Hat (4.4.7-3) and facing same problem . Installing 0.98 version of rstudio worked for me.